# How to read multiple excel sheets in vb6?

Tags: excel, vb6

I want to read the multiple excel sheets with `vb 6.0`.

What I'm trying to do is I want to read the Excel columns from multiple sheets and then insert into respective Table:

For example, lets say that there are three sheets in one Excel file.

Read first sheet's data columns and then insert into **Table A**.
Then, read second sheet's data columns and then insert into **Table B**.
For the third sheet, read the data columns and then insert into **Table C**.

I already know how to read data columns from a single sheet, but don't know yet to read from multiple sheets. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you share your code on how you are reading one so that we have something to go by since there are many ways to read excel

Comment: insert your code as suggested above but you probably need to look at Arrays

Comment: Are you using COM/OLE Automation to read Excel columns? Are you using ADO to access the database?